# How do I store a $_SESSION value within my database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I've been trying to store the session `userUid` and put it in the database under id. I want it to merge the two ids from different databases.

I tried setting the `userUid` as a variable and putting it into the database. `userUid` is the id from the signup/login page and profiles is the database i'm trying to insert it into.

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['userUid'])){ 
    header("location: index.php"); // Redirecting To Home Page 

    $switch = $_SESSION['userUid'];
    $Asql = "INSERT INTO profile (id) VALUES ('$switch');" ;
    mysqli_query($conn2, $Asql);
    $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if ($resultCheck > 0) {
          while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
              echo $row['id'] . "<br>";
          }
    }
}
```

I expect it to out put the newly inserted `$_SESSION['userUid']` as "id" from the database profiles.

Answer (score 2):

A few things to note,

- Your current logic will never really work, because you only execute the query when the session-value is *not* set
- You should always `exit;` after a `header("Location:...");` call
- You should be using prepared statements and bind your values through placeholders
- An insert query has no `num_rows` (the equivalent is `affected_rows` for insert/update/delete queries) or `fetch_*()` methods associated with them.

```php
if (!isset($_SESSION['userUid'])) { 
    header("location: index.php"); // Redirecting To Home Page 
    exit;
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO profile (id) VALUES (?);";
$stmt = $conn2->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $_SESSION['userUid']);
$stmt->execute();
echo $stmt->affected_rows." rows inserted";
$stmt->close();
```

In order to properly check for errors, you should enable MySQLi exception mode by adding the following line *before* you create your MySQLi connection. That means that you have to use a `try/catch` for your query statements, but in turn means that you don't have to do individual error-checking for each function-call.

```php
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use `mysqli_fetch_assoc` on an insert query.
You could either just use `$_SESSION['userUid']` or you can make a seperate select query to get the new row from the database.

Answer (score -1):

First check the "if" condition in your code.
`if(!isset($_SESSION['userUid'])):
...
else:
...
endif;`

The final solution to you,

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['userUid'])):
header("location: index.php"); // Redirecting To Home Page 
else:
$switch = $_SESSION['userUid'];
$Asql = "INSERT INTO profile (id) VALUES ('$switch');" ;
mysqli_query($conn2, $Asql);
$resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
  if ($resultCheck > 0):
      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
          echo $row['id'] . "<br>";
       }
   endif;
endif;
```